# In Google cloud deployment manager yaml file how to configure sourceImage as a custom image present in our project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In this link - https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-basic-configuration

initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9

Need to put my custom image which does not have image family.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value that you need to put in the configuration file like this:

1. Go to Console -> Compute Engine -> CREATE INSTANCE
2. Select your custom image in the "Boot disk" section
3. Click on "Equivalent REST" at the bottom of the page below "Create" and "Cancel"
4. Copy the value of "SourceImage"
5. Paste the value in your yaml configuration file.

[image: Create an instance]